# "The sandbox is not in sync with the Podfile.lock. Run 'pod install..." when pulling from a PC that didn't perform to the last push

Tags: xcode, git, cocoapods

I'm sharing a private repository for an XCode project with a friend of mine. All the project directories are included in it except `Pods` and `DerivedData`. The problem is the following:

1. If I perform a push, whenever the other guy pulls to update its local copy, his XCode throws "The sandbox is not in sync with the Podfile.lock. Run 'pod install..." error and he's forced to delete `podfile.lock` and `profilename.xcworkspace`, then run `pod install` to fix.
2. If he performs a push, whenever I pull to update my local copy (and so on, same as above).

To try and fix the issue we tried to delete the remote repository versions of `podfile.lock` and `profilename.xcworkspace` and push from whatever was the most recent of our copies. Didn't work of course.

Other things we came up with were trying to remove from version control `podfile.lock` (which is not recommended by Cocoapods' [guidelines](https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/using-cocoapods.html) anyway) and `projectname.xcworkspace`

> Whether or not you check in the Pods directory, the Podfile and Podfile.lock should always be kept under version control.

We ended up not even trying this last solution because the drawbacks seem to be unacceptable.

Last thing we tried was to clean XCode's derived data before pulling. Didn't work either.

Comment: How do you "share" a private repo? Do you use a standard Private Cocoa Pods approach, which is described under the link below?
https://guides.cocoapods.org/making/private-cocoapods.html

Comment: @YuriSolodkin: I shared my private repo with my friend by inviting him as a collaborator from the project's settings. We don't have private pods, we just use it to embed `Introspect` and `RealmSwift` into out project.

Comment: Right, so you're using only public Cocoa Pods repos. Then you should keep Podfile and Podfile.lock under the version control. Podfile.lock will specify the versions of libraries you're using. Once you performed pod update or pod install for the first time, it will install the pods and update Podfile.lock. Now, if you do not run 'pod update' anymore, you should not be prompted with this error if you have your local pods in place. If you still have a problem, then I would work out why your local pods become out of sync with podfile.lock. Maybe your pull overrides it...

Comment: @YuriSolodkin: We never ran `pod update` in our local copies of the repository, only `pod install` when first cloned the directory, but we keep getting this error. I wonder if there's any known possible set of things that could cause `podfile.lock` to be overridden by a pull, I couldn't find much about it.

Comment: If you include podfile.lock into source control, you can make sure it was not changed. Why do you avoid including it under the source control?